# awk script to print info at specific lines

Tags: linux, command-line, awk, format, line

i have some data files, and i need to pull some info out.  i'd like to use a single awk script to get data out, so i can suck some data into bash arrays.

for this, let's assume i need the following (1-indexed):
 - i need awk to print column one on lines 2, 3, and 4
 - i need awk to print columns 1, 2, and 3 on lines 8 and over.  but i want all of the column ones printed before the column twos, and the column twos before the column threes.

using the following data example:

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno
1a1
2b2
11 22 33 44
55 66 77 88
99 00 12 13
14 15 16 17
```

i would want awk to print the string:

```
def ghi jkl 11 55 99 14 22 66 00 15 33 77 12 16
```

i created the following, which i thought would work, but i am getting an error saying "END bocks must have an action part".

```
awk '
BEGIN {i=0;}
{
   if ((NR >= 2) && (NR <= 4))
      print $1;
   if (NR >= 8)
   {
      col1_arr[i] = $1;
      col2_arr[i] = $2;
      col3_arr[i] = $3;
      i++;
   }
}
END
{
   for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
       print col1_arr[j];
   for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
       print col2_arr[j];
   for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
       print col3_arr[j];
}' /path/to/my/file
```

thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Slightly verbose. But that's fine it makes it maintainable if you want to keep it. The code for END must start on the same line as the END.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work -

```
awk '
BEGIN{i=0;}
NR>=2 && NR<=4 {printf $1" "} 
NR >=8 {col1[i]=$1;col2[i]=$2;col3[i]=$3;i++;} 
END{for (i=0;i<=NR-8;i++) printf col1[i]" "; for(i=0;i<=NR-8;i++) printf col2[i]" ";for (i=0;i<=NR-8;i++) printf col3[i]" "}' INPUT_FILE


[jaypal:~/Temp] cat data
abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno
1a1
2b2
11 22 33 44
55 66 77 88
99 00 12 13
14 15 16 17

[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '
BEGIN{i=0;}
NR>=2 && NR<=4 {printf $1" "} 
NR >=8 {col1[i]=$1;col2[i]=$2;col3[i]=$3;i++;} 
END{for (i=0;i<=NR-8;i++) printf col1[i]" "; for(i=0;i<=NR-8;i++) printf col2[i]" ";for (i=0;i<=NR-8;i++) printf col3[i]" "}' data
def ghi jkl 11 55 99 14 22 66 00 15 33 77 12 16
```

Comment: just because i don't know enough, will using something like col1[$1]=$1 cause repeated data only to show up once?  would it overwrite itself?  i definitely don't want that to happen.

Comment: Using col[$1]=$1 you are creating an index of $1 and assigning the value of $1 to it. The problem will arise when you have same values in column1. That will cause the index to get overwritten. Plus you won't have a proper way of getting values out in order. That was the reason I had updated my answer. The order would get messed up.

Comment: Just edited the answer to use `NR-row number where multiple records start` so that you don't have to hard code the number of records you have to pop out in the `for loop`.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly verbose. But that's fine it makes it maintainable if you want to keep it.

Each awk rule is:

```
<Match> <Action>
```

Either may be empty:

Empty <Match> means match every line.
Empty <Action> means print (which prints the current line).

Of course END has no line so print becomes meaningless.

What you have is:

```
END  -- No Action --
--No Match -- { print your col arrays }
```

What you need to do is put the action on the same line as the end.

```
END {
for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
   print col1_arr[j];
for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
   print col2_arr[j];
for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
   print col3_arr[j];
}
```

The other problem you are having is that print puts a newline onto the string it prints.
to get around this use `printf("<format string>", variables);`

```
BEGIN {i=0;}
{
    if ((NR >= 2) && (NR <= 4))
        printf("%s ", $1);
    if (NR >= 8)
    {
        col1_arr[i] = $1;
        col2_arr[i] = $2;
        col3_arr[i] = $3;
        i++;
    }
}
END {
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        printf("%d ", col1_arr[j]);
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        printf("%d ", col2_arr[j]);
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        printf("%d ", col3_arr[j]);
}
```

Comment: We would have to give width in all the `printf` statements something like `printf("%02d ", col1_arr[j]);` as there is one value `00` in the OP's data. Without it there would be no padding and the value `00` will get popped out as `0`.

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time to explain that to me.  i appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

the awk line below should do the job for you:

```
awk '(NR==1 || NR>=5 && NR<=7){next;} 
{printf $1" ";if(NR>=8){two[NR]=$2;three[NR]=$3}}
END{for(x in two)printf two[x]" ";for(x in three) printf three[x]" "}' yourFile
```

test with your example:

```
kent$  echo "abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno
1a1
2b2
11 22 33 44
55 66 77 88
99 00 12 13
14 15 16 17 "|
awk '(NR==1 || NR>=5 && NR<=7){next;} 
{printf $1" ";if(NR>=8){two[NR]=$2;three[NR]=$3}}
END{for(x in two)printf two[x]" ";for(x in three) printf three[x]" "}'
```

**output**

```
def ghi jkl 11 55 99 14 22 66 00 15 33 77 12 16
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to work on this.  i never thought about using NR for the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'END {
  printf "%s", (r OFS)
  for (i = 0; ++i <= l;)
    printf "%s", (m[i] (i < l ? OFS : RS))
  }
NR > 1 && NR < 5 {
  r = r ? r OFS $0 : $0
  }
NR >= 8 {
  for (i = 0; ++i <= l;)
    m[i] = i in m ? m[i] OFS $i : $i
  }' l=3 infile
```

Comment: oh man. that is some crazy awk code.  i can't even figure out what is going on.